# Dropping text by a line when pressing return key

Tags: cocoa

I have drawn NSTextView object on NSView, which i added by calling addSubview method.

When I enter text and press enter text i had entered come down by one line correspondingly.

What can be the reason behind it, and how to cope with this problem.

Comment: The text entered before the cursor moves down one line? Or does the cursor move down, as if you had broken the line and started a new one?

Comment: When i enter the text and press enter key, the cursor moves down along with the text.

Answer (score 0):

Just initialise the frame while allocating memory of the NSTextView object, instead of calling setFrame method. This does not create the problem...

Comment: You were previously initializing the view with an `init` message? Don't do that. Always initialize a view with `initWithFrame:`, unless it has a different initializer for you to use, in which case, use that.